# How do I copy a file to a destination with a wildcard?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell

For example, I would like to copy a shortcut.lnk to all of my individual users in windows xp. Therefore I want to do something like this:

```
echo | f xcopy \\server\networkpath\shortcut.lnk "c:\Documents and Settings\%\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\ /Y /f
```

It doesn't matter if its done in CMD or powershell, I just need something that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably do best by looping over the target directories, and copying the file into each.
So something along the lines of

```
set sourcefile=%\\server\networkpath\shortcut.lnk%

if exist %sourcefile% (
  for /D %%to in (insert your target path pattern here) do (
    xcopy %sourcefile% %%to
  )
) ELSE (
echo  %sourcefile% not found
)
```

/D as opposed to /R performs the operation on the directories quoted, as opposed to recursing through them.